# Jquery set droppable based on async call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Im trying to call a method to set whether or not a div is droppable. I found this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYsnc/) based on some googling. How can I allow/disallow dropping based on the async result of my code below? My goal (example):

- div id:drag can be dropped into 1 and foo.
- div id:drag2 can be put into 1 only.

I am having trouble specifying it can only be put in those divs, not the others.

My code to get which divs it can be put in. Can return a string or anything else you need:

```
//TAKES in THE DIV ID
$.getJSON("/Tickets/ChangeCardLane", { id: data }, function (cr) 
 {
if (cr == null) { //droppable==true
}
else{ //droppable==false
}
```

The JSFiddle code reproduced here (with my possibly incorrect comments):

```js
//when drop onto div named #floor
$('#floor').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

//if drop was a success
$('#drag').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        alert("revert invalid: "+$(this).attr('id'));
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
});
```

```css
#other { display:inline-block; width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid silver; background-color:whitesmoke; padding:10px; }

#drag { display:inline-block; width:80px; height:30px; border:1px solid silver; background-color:white; }

#drag2 { display:inline-block; width:80px; height:30px; border:1px solid silver; background-color:white; }

#floor { display:inline-block; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid silver; background-color:yellow; padding:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div id="drag" class="ui-widget-content" onmousedown="shift('drag')">drag me</div>
<div id="drag2" class="ui-widget-content" onmousedown="shift('drag')">drag me2</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="floor">foo</div>
    <div id="other">bar</div>
    <div id="other">1</div>
    <div id="other">2</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You want to pull whether it is draggable or not from an ajax request or the backend itself when your page loads?

Comment: Basically I need to be able to specify which divs id:drag can be dropped in. Onpageload works fine, or dynamic when the div is picked up